# Conditional Probability: question Walpole example

Tags: probability

In the Book Probability and Statistics-Walpole an example of conditional probability appear in this way: Consider the events: 
A= take first an ace and 
B= Take in a second time a spade card, considering that the experiment has card replacement.

So the book p(B|A)= p(A N B)/P(A)= 13/52. I understand why p(ANB) =13, but when we say p(A)=52, I consider that the previous answer (p(A)) is wrong because the probability of event A is 4/52. Could someone explain to me why my reasoning could be wrong?

Thanks and best regards from Colombia,

DFCP.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The first rule of the Fight Club is that a probability always lies between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: You know you shouldn't talk about it, right?

Comment: This is the book solution. And second i dont know what are you talking about, how the example broke that rule?

Comment: When you say "I understand why $p(A\cap B) =13$", it makes me feel like I should reply something funny as well.

Comment: What you missed is that $\frac ab=\frac 35$ does not imply $a=3, b=5$ - they could be a bunch of things.

Comment: When the book says that $P(A,B)/P(A) = 13/52$ is doesn't mean that $P(A. B) = 13$ and $P(A) = 52$. Probabilities are always between 0 and 1. This is the final answer. First you need to know how many aces and how many spade cards are there, relative to the total number of cards with replacement (this will give you the probabilities), and then use the fact that the events $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of an ace P(A) is $\frac{4}{52}=\frac{1}{13}$ because there are 4 aces of 52 equally probable cards.  The probability of a spade P(B) is $\frac{13}{52}=\frac{1}{4}$ because there are 13 spades of 52 equally probable cards.  Because you replaced the the card, the two events are independent of one another and the probability of both is simply the product of the two probabilities, i.e. $\frac{4 \cdot 13}{52 \cdot 52}=\frac{1}{52}$

$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A B)}{P(A)}=\frac{1}{52} \cdot \frac{13}{1}=\frac{1}{4}$

of course since they are independent P(B|A) = P(B) again $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: You´re doing 1/52=p(B|A)*1/13 then p(B|A)= 1/52*13/1=1/4? right? If so, is not clear for me why instead using that previous formula, you don´t use p(B|A)= p(A.B)/P(A) ?

Comment: you can certainly use P(B|A)=P(AB)/PA, P(B|A)=1/52 / 1/13 = 13/52 = 1/4